# Hibernate not able to load 10,000 objects

Tags: java, hibernate, session, performance

I want to load more than 10,000 objects through hibernate, but its not able to do so. It keeps no writing these lines in the log.

```
 Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after HibernateTemplate
 Found thread-bound Session for HibernateTemplate
```

I just want to know is there ay efficient way to do it or we will just can't load these many objects in hibernate session

Comment: How are you loading them? What do you want to do with these 10,000 entities? Show us some code.

Comment: @JB..I don't think it has very much to do with the code. ......I just wanted to know the behavior of hibernate in such extreme cases..you guys can yourself suggest a code if it is possible in hibernate to load these many objects.

Comment: You don't tell if you're executing a single query, or looping through 10,000 IDs and loading each entity one by one, or something else. You don't say if the session is read-only or not. If it's a stateless session or not. Consider reading the documentation. It has a whole chapter dedicated to batch operations.